# .trigger("click") doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="navTab">
   <li onclick="setTimeout(breadcrumbChange, 200);" class="active">
     <a href="#stepOne" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
       <br>#rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_CLIENT_PROJECT_TAB#
     </a>
   </li>
   <li onclick="setTimeout(breadcrumbChange, 200);" class="disabled">
     <a href="#stepTwo" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
       <br>#rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_BASE_PRODUCT_SELECTION_TAB#
     </a>
   </li>
   <li onclick="setTimeout(breadcrumbChange, 200);" class="disabled">
     <a href="#stepThree" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-magic"></i>
       <br>#rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_DESIGN_STYLE_TAB#
     </a>
   </li>
   <li onclick="setTimeout(breadcrumbChange, 200);" class="disabled">
     <a href="#stepFour" data-toggle="tab">
       <i class="fa fa-gift"></i>
       <br>#rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_ORDER_REVIEW_TAB#
     </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

And I have a button

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-template-main btnNext"> 
        #rn:msg:CUSTOM_MSG_COMPLETE_ORDER_CMD#<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </a>
 </div>
```

I put an event handler to get the "button" click :

```
$('.btnNext').click(function() {
   $('#navTab li.active').next('li').removeClass('disabled');
   $('#navTab li.active').next('li').find('a').attr("data-toggle", "tab");
   $('#navTab li.active').next('li').find('a').trigger("click");   
});
```

When I click on the "button" `removeclass` and `.attr` work perfectly , but the `.trigger` is not working. Does anyone know why?

Comment: just use $('#navTab li.active').next('li').find('a').click()

Answer (score 3):

`.trigger()` will only execute the associated event handler,  It will not actually click the element. If no event handlers are assiocaited it will not perform any action.

However, You can use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the reference of underlying DOM element, then native `click()` can be executed.

```
$('#navTab li.active').next('li').find('a').get(0).click()
```